# from X import * , skip pydoc documentation

Tags: python, pydoc

I want to import `*` from module `X` into `main` module, but without importing X's documentation. Example:

```
# X.py
class Class:
    '''Surplus description'''
    ...
```

and the main:

```
# main.py
'''My only document'''
from X import *
```

Now `pydoc main` will show documentation from `X` and `main`, and I don't want `X` docs here

**Related**:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639847/python-pydocs-showing-imported-modules-from-nltk-cannot-remove-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the [`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) attribute, pydoc will only show objects listed there.